# How scheme of Replication works in hadoop3.x?

Tags: azure, replication, hadoop3

As per my understanding in Hadoop-3.x they introduced the **support for Microsoft Azure Data Lake filesystem** and the **scheme of Replication is changed**. Are these only the major features, are any other new features they are introducing as part of hadoop-3.x.?

And how **scheme of Replication** works in Hadoop-3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop 3.0 will incorporate Erasure Coding in place of replication consuming comparatively less storage space whilst providing same level of fault tolerance.

Hadoop 3x replication scheme leading to 200% additional storage space and resource overhead.

For more details, refer “[HDFS Erasure Coding](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSErasureCoding.html)”.

To understand the how HDFS Erasure Coding works,
Refer: “[Introduction to HDFS Erasure Coding in Apache Hadoop](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/09/introduction-to-hdfs-erasure-coding-in-apache-hadoop/)”.